# Can't move hair particles using G, R or S

Tags: particle-edit-mode

I cant transform any of my hairparticles on various meshes. The combing tools does work but I want to manually make changes by using <kbd>G</kbd>.

[image: viewport]

Comment: You need to convert your hair to real curves, your particles now are basically instances, so you only have access to move them with the particles tools

Comment: Thanks but it changed the look I wanted so Ime sticking with the particle tools, thankyou still for clearing it up.